# This Method keeps giving me a null pointer exception, not quite sure why

Tags: methods, nullpointerexception

```
public int calculateWholeAmount()
{
 int wholeAmount = 0;
 Dice[] amountOfDice;
 amountOfDice = new Dice[getDiceAmount()];
 for(int i = 0; i < amountOfDice.length ; i++)
{
 int x = amountOfDice[i].wuerfeln();
 wholeAmount = wholeAmount + x;
}
 return wholeAmount;
}
```

//This method is supposed to be there to create a flexible amount of dice that i can throw. Problem is When starting the method by itself i get a nullpoint exception not sure why.

Comment: You'll need to debug it nullpointerexceptions ate extremely common.

Comment: Dice[] amountOfDice;
 amountOfDice = new Dice[amountOfDice]; //How many Dices are you allocating here ?

Comment: On line 5, you're trying to use an uninitialized array to initialize... itself. Probably your problem.

Comment: Ye sorry i copied it wrong.... I fixed the copy problem.. now it should be all correct, still have the same problems tho will nullpoint exception  amountOfDice = new Dice[getDiceAmount()];

Comment: @IsuckAtProgramming That suggest getDiceAmount is returning a null. You're also never initializing the dice array. You need to fill it with dice before you can use `[]` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using amountOfDice (line 5) before it is initialized.

amountOfDice = new Dice[amountOfDice];

Initialized it before using to fix your problem. For example:
amountOfDice = new Dice[5];

**Edit:**
In your updated code you're calling .lenght on an array. If that array is null (when your method returns 0), it will throw a nullpointer exception. So you must make sure that .length is getting called on an array that's not null.

```
if(amountOfDice != null) { /*your code*/ }
```

In the code above I've made an example of a check how to verify if your array is not null. Inside that if-statement you can call the for-loop. Of course you can also try/catch your exception, but this is not best practice as you know where the problem appears. So just use the above code arround your forloop.

Or make sure that your method (getDiceAmount()) will never return 0 or null. But once again, if someone changes your method, you'll hit the same problem in the future again as others don't know your implementation.

Comment: woops just realized i made a mistake with copy and pasting ^^ .Ok now have another go at it ^^

Comment: Are you sure that there is no way that getDiceAmount() returns 0? Because calling .lenght on a null object will throw a nullpointer exception.